# CSS :hover pseudo not working on nav item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with a :hover psuedo on a menu item. I'm  using Bootstrap and overriding using my own stylesheet. I've researched this a bit on the community and have found out that I cant apply a :hover to an inline-block element, but this is a block element. I'm thinking maybe the  bootstrap classes are somehow overriding the :hover, but I've called my custom.css after the boostrap.css in the html head so ...

Here's [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baskinco/4c8bxpjw/) and the code is below.

```css
.nav-item {
  font-family: LubalinGraphStd-Medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 28px;
  color: #444b4b;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #009ca6;
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register:hover {
  background-color: #009ca6;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-item-register" href="#register">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

Any clues and/or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: And what is the exact behaviour you are expecting please?

Comment: It seems to work fine in the fiddle (using Firefox)(the `nav-item-register`, that is), and from the looks of your code, this ought to work. Have you tried appending the hated `!important` tag? If that solves it, at least you know it is somehow overridden by Bootstrap or other CSS

Comment: What version of boostrap do you use? Works in bootstrap 4 (if you remove the navbar-default selector): http://www.bootply.com/KZDkdSKvfE

Comment: Tijmen: good reminder! when i add !important it works. so somehow the bootstrap.css is overriding my custom.css. how is that possible when i called custom.css after bootstrap.css in my code?

Comment: Pete: im using 3 ... and when I remove navbar-default it works for me as well. guess I found where the issue lies, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selectors don't match any elements in the given code. Is there more code which is missing (namely, any parent elements of `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">`?

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover` does not match any elements as there is no element with a class of `navbar-default`.

If you add a `<div class="navbar-default">` around this code block, it works; fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wcso43a1/2/. Full code:

```
<div class="navbar-default">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li>
                   <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a class="nav-item nav-item-register" href="#register">Register</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- end of navbar-default -->

<!-- CSS -->

.nav-item {
  font-family: LubalinGraphStd-Medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 28px;
  color: #444b4b;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover{
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color:#009ca6;
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register:hover {
  background-color: #009ca6;
}
```

Comment: all of those classes are standard bootstrap 3 classes and using !important on the hover background I've determined that somehow the bootstrap.css is overriding.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the above code appears to work in jsfiddle. I've updated the fiddle here to include bootstrap CSS/JS and still works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/wcso43a1/3/. If there's something still not working could you post a fuller code example or maybe explain in a different way what's not working, as those hovers work fine in fiddle?

Comment: It totally worked in fiddle for me too, but thats because the navbar-default class was somehow conflicting with the :hover on .nav-item-register. I ended up fixing it by removing the navbar-default class completely (like you did in your fiddle) ... now its working great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
.nav-item:hover {
  color: pink;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4c8bxpjw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.nav-item:hover` as the selector for the hovering (instead of `.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover`

```css
.nav-item {
  font-family: LubalinGraphStd-Medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 28px;
  color: #444b4b;
  height: 50px;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #009ca6;
  color: #009ca6;
}

.nav-item-register:hover {
  background-color: #009ca6;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item" href="item.html">item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-item nav-item-register" href="#register">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: I was asking about the nav-item-register hover action specifically, but about your comment: I did try your suggestion for the hover on the other nav-items and it doesn't work. For some reason bootstrap.css is overriding a ton of my custom.css ... im sure its an inheritance thing, but to be honest I'm still trying to wrap my head around how that works when overriding bootstrap styles. At this point im just !important on everything that doesn't work until i figure it out.